# Why is my function not returning anything?

Tags: php, function

Here is my function

```
function get_products($business_id){
    $sql = "SELECT
          b.*, b.name as business_name, p.builder_id,
          bs.*, p.price, p.name as product_name, p.description, p.image, p.per_station, p.skip_screen
        FROM 
          builder_product bp
        JOIN builder_step bs ON bp.builder_step_id = bs.builder_step_id
      JOIN builder b ON bp.builder_id = b.builder_id
        WHERE b.business_id = '{$business_id}' 
        ORDER by b.step_number, b.price";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $steps = array();
    while($row_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $steps["all_steps"]['business_id'] = $business_id;
        $steps["business_name"] = $row_r['business_name'];
        $steps["builder_id"] = $row_r['builder_id'];

    if (count($steps) == 0) {   
        $business_id = 59;
        get_products($business_id);
    }else{
        $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
        return $steps;
    }
}
```

Here is the call to the function

```
$products = get_products($_GET['business_id']);
```

Why is it I am not getting a return from this function....I do a print_r right before the return and I have my array with tons of data but if i do a print_r below the call to this function I get nothing. I am doing a recursive call to ensure i have a return array...any ideas what i am missing

Comment: *sigh* http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You only have a `return` statement in the `else` case. If you don't enter the `else` case, you won't return a value.

Comment: I do enter the else ...i am doing a print_r right before the return and i get the array

Comment: you're missing a closing brace on that while

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a return statement to the `if (count($steps) == 0)` branch of the code:

```
if (count($steps) == 0) {   
    $business_id = 59;
    return get_products($business_id);
}else{
    $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
    return $steps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($steps) == 0) {   
    $business_id = 59;
    get_products($business_id);
}else{
    $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
    return $steps;
}
```

When you hit the if, instead of the else, nothing is returned.

edit:  change that to `return get_products($business_id)`.

Comment: but isnt the recussive calling the function again and the second time around it wont hit the if it will hit the else

Comment: @Tamer but you still need to put a 'return' in front of the get_products function.

Comment: See my edit.  When you call something recursively like that, you will want to use a return, not just call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have return in you if:

```
if (count($steps) == 0) {   
        $business_id = 59;
        get_products($business_id);
        return $whatYouwant;
    }else{
        $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
        return $steps;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the whole function?  Looks like your missing a closing bracket:

```
function get_products($business_id){
    $sql = "SELECT
          b.*, b.name as business_name, p.builder_id,
          bs.*, p.price, p.name as product_name, p.description, p.image, p.per_station, p.skip_screen
        FROM 
          builder_product bp
        JOIN builder_step bs ON bp.builder_step_id = bs.builder_step_id
      JOIN builder b ON bp.builder_id = b.builder_id
        WHERE b.business_id = '{$business_id}' 
        ORDER by b.step_number, b.price";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $steps = array();
    while($row_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $steps["all_steps"]['business_id'] = $business_id;
        $steps["business_name"] = $row_r['business_name'];
        $steps["builder_id"] = $row_r['builder_id'];

        if (count($steps) == 0) {   
           $business_id = 59;
           get_products($business_id);
        }else{
           $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
          return $steps;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ....

```
if (count($steps) == 0) {   
    $business_id = 59;
    $steps = get_products($business_id);
    $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
    return $steps;
}else{
    $steps["business_id"] = $business_id;
    return $steps;
}
```

I needed to catch the return from the function in an array